# Emacs unable to execute shell commands despite them being in the Emacs shell PATH

Tags: shell, shell-command, shell-mode

I am on Ubuntu. I'm trying to run the `latex` command to run in the Emacs shell. I have done some research, and have already done the following:

I noticed that running `env` in the Emacs shell gave a different value for PATH than running `env` in the normal terminal. I installed purcell's `exec-path-from-shell` to solve this. Following the directions, I copied my current terminal `PATH`, went to `.profile`, commented out lines of the kind `PATH = something_new:PATH` and just replaced it all with `PATH=my_whole_copied_path`. I then added `(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)` just after `(package-initialize)` in my `.emacs`.

After doing this, running `env` in Emacs shell gives the same `PATH` as running `env` in my terminal. The latex binary lives in `/opt/texbin`, and my current Emacs `PATH` reads:

```
'PATH=/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
```

Still, running latex give `command not found`. What am I missing?

Update: I have learned that `/opt/texbin` is actually a symlink to a different location, and I've noticed that I can't `cd` into it in the Emacs shell. Could this be why this isn't working? Can I get shell to understand symlinks with an option?

Answer (score 3):

Solved it: it was because Emacs was installed as a flatpak. For some reason, this mean the Emacs shell had many differences. I wasn't able to `cd` into certain folders. Other folders didn't exist: `/usr/local`, for example.

After uninstalling, and re-installing from the Ubuntu repository, everything works as expected.

I hope this can be helpful to someone. My `PATH` was setup fine, and I was still running into this problem. I'd love it if someone could explain why installing it as a flatpak caused the Emacs shell to "see" such a different set of directories.

Comment: Ran into the same issue, my solution was installing from `snap`.